# VBA: non- contiguous ranges - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I create a range object using Union to group together some non-contiguous ranges. I then pass it to a sub trying to set the borders of these non-contiguous ranges. Excel throws an error message of "Object doesn't support this property or method." I think the code should work for a single range. So, the question is when it comes to multiple ranges, what is the proper code to use?

```
..............      
For record_num = 1 To Total_Record_Num - 1 Step 1
Set rng3 = Union(rng3, .Range("A" & record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 1 & ":C" & record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 2))
Next record_num
...........
set_border1 rng3
..............
End Sub

.......another sub ....
Sub set_border1(rng As Range)

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").rng   '<= problematic code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worksheets do not have a `rng` method.  You can omit `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` because `rng` is already qualified to a Worksheet.

> With rng